# Video freezes when VLC player is in full screen mode

Tags: sound, video, vlc

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. Everything went fine and the upgrade was successful. But, after a few days, I played a .mp4 video with VLC player. The video played in full screen mode for 3 to 4 seconds and then the screen froze. The audio kept playing, but the video stopped, and both the keyboard and mouse stopped responding. The only way to get out of this was to force the computer to shutdown and restart it.

This happens every time with Ubuntu 18.04, but I never experienced this problem with 16.04.

I am a huge VLC fan. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is exactly what happens when a graphics card starts to fail, however I don't think this applies because VLC worked fine on 16.04. Therefore I suspect a graphics driver issue instead. Please edit your question and copy/paste the results of `lspci | grep VGA` and `ubuntu-drivers devices`

Comment: You could also try deleting the .config/vlc folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I don't know exactly what causes this bug.
But... 
One (temporary) solution I found is to hide the player in full-screen mode:

Go to **Interface Preferences** (**Tools** -> **Preferences**) and uncheck the option **Show controls in full screen mode**.
This simple trick will allow you to watch your .mp4 files in full-screen mode without freeze all the system.

(I'm waiting for a definitive bug fix too)

[image: Interface Preferences]

[A thread about this bug on the VideoLan Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=146103)

Comment: It helps, but it seems it's not real the cause of the problem.